# eXist-db eXide editor not showing collections

Tags: exist-db, exide

When I open eXide while running eXist-db it doesn't show any of my collections.  I recently updated to the latest version and now the collections show in the dashboard but not in eXide.

Comment: Please be specific: Which version of eXist and eXide?

Comment: eXist 3.2.0  eXide version 2.1.2

Comment: Have you tried shift-reloading the page? Sometimes eXide assets are stale from previous sessions. Falling that, can you post a screenshot of the pane where the problem is evident?

Comment: Also, if you upgraded from a previous version of eXist, you may have forgotten to do a backup and restore — the recommended upgrade procedures as outlined at http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/upgrading.xml. After restoring your data, be sure to follow the instructions at http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/backup.xml#D2.2.8.5 to ensure apps like eXide (i.e., apps installed into eXist's EXPath Package repository) are properly re-registered.